# how to sort rows of an R dataframe based on a binary condition within subjects

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataset composed of the following columns

```
Subject_Number     Condition        .... other columns 
300                drug
300                placebo
299                placebo
298                drug
297                drug 
296                placebo
```

...

As you can see, each participant (e.g. participant number 300) has been analysed on two occasions once with the drug and once with a placebo

Now i am required to do the following: for each participant, I need to make it so the first condition is the drug and the second is the placebo:

```
Subject_Number     Condition        .... other columns 
300                drug
300                placebo
299                drug
298                placebo
297                drug 
296                placebo
...
```

Can you help me find out how to do this? Thanks!

I can sort or order the dataframe based on the condition column but then it will change the dataframe in a way where first it shows all the drug rows, then all the placebo rows together. I don't want that. I need to make it so *within each subject number* the drug row comes first and the placebo row comes second.
Hope I explained myself!

Comment: Sort by subject, then by condition, with `dplyr` `your_data %>% arrange(Subject_Number, Condition)`.

Comment: Try `i<-order(df$Condition, df$Subject_Number); sorted_df<-df[i,]`.